# How can 'ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv' be resized to use all the space in sda3?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              384M  1.1M  383M   1% /run
**/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G   16G  171G   9% /**   primary partition here 
tmpfs                              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12398
/dev/loop2                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/20326
/dev/loop4                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12159
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop5                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2066
/dev/loop3                          70M   70M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19188
/dev/sda2                          976M  203M  707M  23% /boot
tmpfs                              384M     0  384M   0% /run/user/1000
```

vs.

```
myuser@ubuntu20:~$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                         2:0    1    4K  0 disk
loop0                       7:0    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2074
loop1                       7:1    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12398
loop2                       7:2    0 67.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/20326
loop3                       7:3    0 69.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19188
loop4                       7:4    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12159
loop5                       7:5    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2066
sda                         8:0    0  800G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  799G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  199G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

How can I make `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` **consume the entire 799 GBs?**

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
   lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

And then resize the fs by running

```
   resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Comment: Can this be done from the running system, or must it be done from a live USB for example? Is it possible to combine the steps by adding `--resizefs` to the `lvextend` command?

Comment: I would run it from the system.

Comment: Thanks. The commands did not work, sorry to say.